# Need login all time while running test in Protractor

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I have written e2e tests in protractor but stucked in a problem. Every time i run the tests in chromedriver, it does not take the login from the existing chrome browser where already exists an active user session.

**Is there any way to use the already active user session when running tests with protractor, chromediver and chrome browser?**

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible because when Protractor kicks off the webDriver it opens a fresh browser with no cookies or history.

You will have to make Protractor login at the beginning.